# What is a good way to do AngularJS databinding in a HTML file that is requested by server side NodeJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, data-binding

I have an HTML file which I import in my nodejs file. How do I go about doing the databinding in HTML file so that when I request the file, the AngularJS databinding will be executed? Right now, using readFileSync is just returning the original contents of my file without executing any AngularJS code.

app.js

```
var file= fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public/file.html').toString();
```

Inside the file.html, I have a databinded variable {{name}}. I've initialized Angular and tied in my controller, not getting any errors anywhere so not sure why variable doesn't get databinded?

Comment: Please explain use case in more detail. Angular doesn't currently have a server side api

Comment: @charlietfl edited original post, does that help clarify the issue I'm having?

Comment: Not really...are you expecting it to be compiled in node? or are you sending that to browser to compile?

Comment: Yea, shouldn't node.js execute what's inside the file when it reads it? If not, how would I go about doing databinding in that case?

Comment: No...angular runs in browser. If you want compiled version you need to use a headless

Comment: Are you saying I could use something like PhantomJS to execute AngularJS code from NodeJS file?

Comment: Yes run app in phantom and use a dom parser to do whatever it is you want